# subdomains for different wordpress directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have staging.namexx.my and staging2.namexx.my now.

for staging.made4u.my, it's using directoryA

**And now, i want staging2.namexx.my to use directoryB** to open wordpress

*staging.namexx.my is currently working, just need to  let staging to use directoryA, and staging2 to use directoryB in same server.

I'm playing with the htaccess and google for some time but still cannot get it.

I need some help.

my htaccess in root

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(staging.)?namexx.my$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dicrectoryA/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dicrectoryA/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(staging.)?namexx.my$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ dicrectoryA/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

htaccess in directoryA

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dicrectoryA/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dicrectoryA/index.php [L]
</IfModule>   
# END WordPress
```

htacesss in directoryB

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directoryB/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /directoryB/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thank you!

Comment: What folder is your `staging2.made4u.my` curruntly pointing to meaning that when you type `staging2.made4u.my` in browser what folder is served .

Comment: @AmitVerma the apache default page.

Comment: Where is your Apache default page located?

Comment: @AmitVerma the root folder.. i mean www/html/

Answer (score 0):

To point `staging2.namexx.my` to `directoryB` via rewrite , you could use the following rule in your `root/. htaccess` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging2\.namexx\.my$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directoryB%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Just replace `staging2.namexx.my` with your real domain name and keep the rule block at the top of your htaccess.